# My creation of a simple object is not working correctly?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a simple object and then use a constructor to fill that object just like you can in an OOP language. Why is Javascript not letting me create a basic object

```
person = new Object();
```

**Question: What would be the best way to declare an object in Javascript so that it basically follows that same convesion as Java and C++?**

I would like to be able to add in the object properties before I use them in the code.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

person=new Object(); <-- will work with out this code

function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor)
{
this.firstname=firstname;
this.lastname=lastname;
this.age=age;
this.eyecolor=eyecolor;
}

myFather=new person("John","Doe",50,"blue");

document.write(myFather.firstname + " -- " + myFather.age);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that JavaScript *is* an OOP language. It's just prototype based instead of class based.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What's the problem with the constructor?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. First you declare a function (`person`, notice, that functions in JS are hoisted), then you override it with an empty object...

Comment: *What would be the best way to declare an object in Javascript so that it basically follows that same convesion[sic] as Java and C++?*: Different language, different conventions. Don't fight to try and get the language to work the same as some other language or you'll be frustrated for a long time.

Comment: See also [stackoverflow creating objects in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843951/which-way-is-best-for-creating-an-object-in-javascript-is-var-necessary-befor)

Answer (score 2):

```
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor)
{
this.firstname=firstname;
this.lastname=lastname;
this.age=age;
this.eyecolor=eyecolor;
}

myFather=new person("John","Doe",50,"blue");

document.body.innerHTML=myFather.firstname + " -- " + myFather.age;
```

works, you dont need `person=new Object()` since your are defining person in a function statement anyway. In javascript, functions are object constructors too.That's why you can call `new` on functions.

http://jsfiddle.net/camus/bBj8f/

> Question: What would be the best way to declare an object in
>   Javascript so that it basically follows that same convesion as Java
>   and C++?

Javascript doesnt have to follow Java or C++ "conventions", Javascript doesnt work like Java or C++ .

Comment: I was going to post this myself, but the OP states this in his question, I have no idea what he's asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
person=new Object();
```

is not needed here. Just remove that line and your code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/s5UDq/

Answer (score 1):

Just a small dissection of your code:

Here you are creating a (global variable) with an object inside.

```
person=new Object();
```

The line next you are creating a new function named `person`: note that is not a variable with the function as value.

```
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor){
  this.firstname=firstname;
  this.lastname=lastname;
  this.age=age;
  this.eyecolor=eyecolor;
}
```

After that you are using the named function as implicit constructor for the object `person`.

The solution would be to either create a variable person, with the function as a value, or just the named function.

For the former have a look to this:

```
  var person = function(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor){
    this.firstname=firstname;
    this.lastname=lastname;
    this.age=age;
    this.eyecolor=eyecolor;
  }
```

For the latter, just remove the `person = new Object();` line.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution:**
Remove the line `person = new Object();` and then your code works as expected.

**The reason:**
The reason why you're getting an error in your code is because of **function hoisting** in javascript (see http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting). Because of this the function `player` gets defined above all. After that you overwrite the function `player` with a emtpy object (with the line `person = new Object();`).

So this is why there is an error like this: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

Have a look at the additional comments:

```
console.log(person); // logs function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor) ...

person=new Object(); // here you overwrite your function

function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor) // at this point the function is already declared
{
this.firstname=firstname;
this.lastname=lastname;
this.age=age;
this.eyecolor=eyecolor;
}

console.log(person); // logs Object {}

myFather=new person("John","Doe",50,"blue"); // Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

console.log(myFather.firstname + " -- " + myFather.age);
```

Comment: If i open a page in Google Chrome will it show me all the errors on the page?

Comment: no, you can see the error in the javascript console (you can get to the console with the key F12)