# Using objects with function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am new to javascript development .i have learned about javascript objects and i have done some code with it ..My code

```
function afunction() { 
var num = 10;
return num;
}

afunction.randomfunction(function() {

return {

"name": "somename"

"age": 12
}

})
```

When i called the function with  `afunction.randomfunction.name;` it gives me error like

```
" underfined is not a function"
```

i dont know why am getting like this .what i need is that i need to get the the value of name object by using `afunction.randomfunction.name;`

i know am doing something wrong ..Hope you guys can help me .to find out my mistake.

Comment: `afunction.randomfunction.name` is not correct code in this context because `randomfunction` doesn't exist, nor is it a child of `afunction`. Why do you have this code? What are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: `afunction` doesn't have the property of `randomfunction `, so `afunction.randomfunction ` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Dai i just want to get value of name ie somename by using afunction.randomfunction(function() { })

Comment: @xdazz can you provide me an example in answer to add property to randomfunction .so that i can understand it better

Comment: What is `afunction.randomfunction` supposed to be?   Is it supposed to be a function?  If so, you have to define it as a function before you can call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the function `randomFunction` isn't defined in `aFunction`. You need to either define it as a separate function like this

```
function randomFunction(){
    //code
}
```

and call it by `randomFunction();`

or if you want to create an object with a public function you can create it for example like this

```
function YourObject(){

    var num = 10; //think of this as a constructor

    this.getNum = getNum; //this "attaches" the getNum() function code to the getNum variable of YourObject
    function getNum(){
        return this.num;
    }

    this.randomFunction = randomfunction;
    function randomFunction(){
        //code
    }
}
```

afterwards you can call your object's method like this

```
var yourObject = new YourObject(); //instantiate
console.log(youObject.getNum()); //print the value of yourObject.num to console
yourObject.randomFunction(); //execute your random function
```

Note: There are more approaches on creating objects in JavaScript, this is just one. You might find [Which way is best for creating an object in javascript? is "var" necessary before variable of object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843951/which-way-is-best-for-creating-an-object-in-javascript-is-var-necessary-befor) interesting.

Comment: i dont want to do like this i want to do as @quentin said but when i run his code it shows SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to **call** `randomfunction` and pass it a function expression instead of just assigning a function expression.

Change `obj.foo(x)` to `obj.foo = x`.

Then you can call it — `obj.foo()` — and access return values from it: `obj.foo().property`.

---

```
function afunction() {
    var num = 10;
    return num;
}

afunction.randomfunction = function () {
    return {
        "name": "somename",
        "age": 12
    };
};

alert(afunction.randomfunction().name);
```

Comment: can you provide me an example ..i want to call two functions like function1.function2(function() { object_here } }) ..and return object value from here

Comment: Err… I did provide you with an example!

Comment: this was the one i wanted ..surely i would accept this answer

Comment: i have a doubt will it work if i use like afunction.randomfunction(function() { return { name: somename }; });

Comment: this dont work ..it says SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: @user3700265: Then fix the error and run the code again. It's easy to spot where the incorrect `)` is.