# Any difference between the object literal and a function returning an object?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell the difference between the following two code samples? From the result aspects, they are pretty much the same, but what are the use cases for these two code snippets? Any difference under the hood? Any pitfalls we need to avoid or need to know before we create our object in JavaScript?

```
var celebrity = {
  celebrityID: 999,
  getID: function ()  {
    return this.celebrityID;
  },
  setID: function (theNewID)  {
    this.celebrityID = theNewID;
  }
}

celebrity.getId(); // 999
celebrity.setId(123);
celebrity.getId(); // 123
```

Vs.

```
function celebrity () {
  var celebrityID = 999;
  return {
    getID: function ()  {
      return celebrityID;
    },
    setID: function (theNewID)  {
        celebrityID = theNewID;
    }
  }
}


​var obj = celebrity();
obj.getID(); // 999
obj.setID(123); 
obj.getID(); // 123
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which way is best for creating an object in javascript? is "var" necessary before variable of object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843951/which-way-is-best-for-creating-an-object-in-javascript-is-var-necessary-befor)

Comment: Lookup the terms ("Javascript" and) "scope", "lexical scoping", "private variables" etc. The second example hides `celebrityId`. Read: http://jargon.js.org/_glossary/REVEALING_MODULE_PATTERN.md or https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1164113/Module-and-Revealing-Module-Patterns-in-JavaScript or many other blog posts about _"revealing module pattern"_ (You do _not_ need to memorize how some people decided to call this specific code pattern - too many people confuse learning words with learning concepts)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are openning a new world for me, I am going to dive in it !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a major difference, from a use-case perspective, in that in the first case `celebrityID` is public, which means this works:

```
celebrity.celebrityID = "foo"
celebrity.getID() // foo
```

This is often undesirable. In the second case `celebrityID` is private. The only access to it is through the getter/setter:

```
var obj = celebrity();
obj.celebrityID = "foo";
obj.getID(); // still 999
```

Another nice thing about the function over the object literal is that you can pass in an argument if you wanted to set the initial value. For example:

```
function celebrity (val) {
    var celebrityID = val || "Default";
    return {
      getID: function ()  {
      return celebrityID;
     },
     setID: function (theNewID)  {
        celebrityID = theNewID;
     }
   }
  }

var obj = celebrity("Foo");
obj.getID(); // 'Foo'

var obj2 = celebrity();
obj2.getID(); // 'Default'
```

Comment: You just revealed the magic of the function closure ! Thank you a lot !