# plain objects VS class instances for model objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, prototypal-inheritance

What is the best practice for creating model objects in Angular / TypeScript:

1. Should I use type annotation with object notation (objects are plain instances of `Object`)? E.g. `let m: MyModel = { name: 'foo' }`
2. Should I use the `new` operator (objects are instances of the respective prototype)?
3. Should these two approaches be mixed up and used situationally? (E.g plain objects, when receiving a response from the `HttpClient`, but `new MyModel('foobar')` for convenience to create instances by passing properties as constructor arguments)

### Background of this question

I'm new to TypeScript and like many other developers I come from popular object oriented languages like Java.

A core concept I understood is that type annotations in TypeScript don't play a role at runtime. They are important for the compiler and for your editor's auto completion. Basically it's ECMAScript with the addition of compile time type checks.

At the time I didn't know this and expected TypeScript to be some kind of "client side Java", I found this Angular bug report:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20770

People (who don't understand TypeScript's type concept) complain about the `HttpClient` not converting the returned plain object to their model class type. Other people are defending this behavior and point out that there are no runtime types in JavaScript.

And here arises my problem: In fact there ARE runtime types in JavaScript. You can create instances of prototypes with the `new` operator and even check their constructor with the `instanceof` operator.

In TypeScript you have two ways for creating an instance:

1) Use the object notation (as they show in the [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#create-a-hero-class)):

```
hero: Hero = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Windstorm'
};
```

2) Use the `new`-operator:

```
hero: Hero = new Hero();
```

At the moment I'm working on a project where these two options are mixed up. I.e. model objects of the same type are instances of `Object` in some cases and instances of `Hero` in other cases.

I expect this leading to problems later, because the constructor is only called in the latter case.

My idea for a rule / best practice was to define all model instances as plain objects and to use the constructor for services, components etc. that are created by dependency injection. As a result I wouldn't use the `new` operator at all.

However I'm not sure if this is a good idea and I couldn't find a *best practice* recommendation about it.

**EDIT**

Important note for close voters: I'm not looking for your personal opionion here. I'm rather looking for some kind of officially documented Angular best practice, as I think it's a core design decision that has to be made right from the project start and these approaches should not be mixed up randomly without a specific reason. Maybe the answer is just a simple "There is no official recommendation which decision to make".

Comment: My personal opinion on the matter : if you use functions from your objects, create an instance of a class. If you only work on the properties, type your answer as an interface.

Comment: I also see a problem with model objects containing arrays of nested objects. With a constructor you can provide an empty array. A plain object's property will be `undefined` and chances for a runtime exception are higher

Comment: That's not an issue with plain objects, that's an issue with your own code. That would be like saying that there's an issue with classes because it doesn't create empty arrays if you don't write it in the constructor.

Comment: My comment was an addition to your's. array properties are another case where true instances have an advantage over plain objects.

Comment: I know, I'm correcting what you said because I find it untrue. And again, class instances don't "have advantage" over plain objects : both handle arrays the same way.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you should use the `new` operator to create new objects of your class if you need to perform complex operations on the object itself.

If in case you just need to access the properties only, you may use the object literal to create a new object.

This has got advantages like encapsulation, inheritance, etc. which a developer coming from the Java background could better relate to.

If you directly assign an object like below, then you have to explicitly set functions in it, for example, `getName` function.

```
hero: Hero = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Windstorm',
  getName: function(){ // returns name }
};
```

However, by defining a class `Hero` with a function `getName` and then creating an instance of that class, you would automatically get that `function`, no matter how many times you create instances.

For a better understanding of Object Oriented Javascript, you may follow the link below:-

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS

---

Regarding the below issue,

> "People (who don't understand TypeScript's type concept) complain
>   about the HttpClient not converting the returned plain object to their
>   model class type."

HttpClient simply returns an object which the server sends, it is on JS to convert it into the required form. You can always map the response into the required model instance by using its constructor which could be defined as below:-

```
constructor(hero){
  this.id = hero.id;
  this.name = hero.name;
}
```

and you may map the array returned from the server like below:-

```
map(hero => new Hero(hero))
```

Comment: I appreciate your opinion, however I'm looking for either an official best practice or want to know if there is a typical way of handling this, because it turned out as best practice over time and nearly everyone is doing it this way. Like, "goto is evil" is an established recommendation. I didn't want to start a discussion here as SO is the wrong place for that. If there is no established best practice I will start a discussion in a forum / newsgroup.

Comment: There is no official doc stating the best practice for creating objects. However, it is totally dependent on the developer and the background he comes from. Using `classes` and the `new` operator simply makes the application more understandable for instance a Java developer. In fact using the `new` operator, you have got wide range of possibilities that you can leverage, probably while enhancing your application, when you might have to write functions for that object / model.

Comment: You may look into the following posts https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-object-creation-patterns-best-practises/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843951/which-way-is-best-for-creating-an-object-in-javascript-is-var-necessary-befor

Answer (score 0):

> In fact there ARE runtime types in JavaScript.

Kind of. A value can have a certain type, however variables and properties don't have types bound to them. That said if you type network requests etc.

```
  fetch("someurl").then(res => res.json()) as Promise<IUser>
```

and that network request suddenly returns something else than a User, nothing will fail as Typescript types do not exist at runtime. However this behaviour can be added easily with typeguards:

```
  function isUser(user: any) : user is IUser {
     return Number.isInteger(user.id) && typeof user.name === "string";
  }
```

which allows you to do typechecks at runtime:

```
 const result = await fetch("someurl");
 if(!isUser(result)) throw new Error();
 // result is definetly a IUser here
```

---

> Should I use inheritance or not?

That is a question of preference. I once wrote an application that works with the db heavily, so I had to do a lot of serialization / deserialization, and it really annoyed me to always wrap the response from the db into a class instance. So for my db models I started using the following pattern:

```
  type User = {
   name: string;
   id: number;
 };

 const User = {
   get(id: number): User { /*...*/ }
   changeName(user: User, name: string) { /*..*/ }
};
```

That allowed me to write:

```
 const admin: User = User.get(123);
```

And I could simply do typecasts on the db and I both had typesafety and nice APIs.

Wether that is a good pattern for your usecase or not really depends on how much serialization / deserialization you do.