# What is the difference between object and class instance in js? The Redux tutorial states they have difference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I thought they are the same, but caution in Redux tutorial states they have difference.

Full text of caution:

> Redux actions and state **should only contain plain JS values like objects**, arrays, and primitives. **Don't put class instances**, functions, or other non-serializable values into Redux!

Comment: does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51742249/plain-objects-vs-class-instances-for-model-objects

Comment: Keyword is _non-serializable_. Anything that cannot be serialized shouldn't be in the redux store. Plain javascript objects are object literals whereas instance is anything created with `new` operator

Comment: I *think* when they say "objects" they refer to object literals (e.g. `{ key: 'value' }`) as opposed to instances (e.g. `new MyClass()`);

Comment: Actually, *non-serialisable* is the wrong keyword here. Many class instances are serialisable just fine. The actual problem is that they are *not deserialisable*, i.e. they will end up as plain objects not class instances and your code breaks when trying to call custom methods.